# How can I make HTTP request from SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, tomcat

I wanted to send an HTTP request from SQL server to Tomcat server. I have installed SQL server 2012 express and non .NET application in Tomcat server. I have gone through this like [Make a HTTP request from SQL server](http://networkprogramming.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/make-a-http-request-from-sql-server/)

As it says in the above article, "The COM object WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 must be installed on the server, some typical variations are WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5".
 I have downloaded winhttp.zip from the [winhttp download link](http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?winhttp), found winhttp.dll in the zip folder and pasted it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER2\MSSQL\Binn` as suggested in this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164653.aspx).

Following that same advice, I have executed following line in SSMS:

```
sp_addextendedproc 'GetHttp',
 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER2\MSSQL\Binn\winhttp.dll';
```

I also executed the following code in SSMS as said in "Make an HTTP request from SQL server link":

```
Alter function GetHttp
(
@url varchar(8000)      
)
returns varchar(8000)
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @win int 
DECLARE @hr  int 
DECLARE @text varchar(8000)

EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'ResponseText',@text OUTPUT
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

RETURN @text
END
```

Then I get the error

> Msg 2010, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetHttp, Line 2
>   Cannot perform alter on 'GetHttp' because it is an incompatible object type.

I do not know how to call the function to send the HTTP request. I assume it is something like this `GetHttp('http://www.google.co.in/')`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't. Just don't. This is not what SQL Server is meant for.

Comment: This is a classic "when you have a hammer, all you see is nails" concept, do NOT do this

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic my requirement is, there is two different databases in different servers(A and B) and one tomcat server's application. If there is any modification in DB A it sends http request to tomcat server's application, app in tomcat server do computation and store data in DB B. So here I need to call the application from sql server only, Since user dosen't have access to app of tomcat server.

Comment: @All Suggest me other ideas.

Comment: Check-out powershell - it has commands for accessing the web and can be called from sql server

Comment: Can't you do this with linked servers?

Comment: @SQLMenace as far as I understand linked servers is more about communication between database servers. but here, what I want is communication between database server and application server.

Comment: Okay, I though you wanted to update data on the other DB server when it changed on the other

Comment: @Jimbo As per my knowledge about powershell is automate various tasks, how can I send http request to remote server by Powershell then. If I wrong correct me.

Comment: Like everyone else said, this is a bad idea. SQL Server has query notifications to let the application know when the data has changed, but it doesn't look like JDBC supports it. You can have the application server poll the DB for changes.

Comment: Like @jtseng mentioned, you could possibly have the app poll for changes, possibly using a "receive from" query as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx

Comment: If I have query notification then I can't initialize app of tomcat server from sql server. Is there any other idea to initialize app from sql server other than http request.

Comment: Powershell has:
Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod

Comment: Can somebody explain *why* it's a bad idea to do it this way. I realise it's a security concern to allow SQL server Active X access. Clearly if it were always an overriding concern, the option wouldn't be possible.
Might this hack be justifiable if an enterprise used it only once or twice and didn't yet own a Powershell skills "hammer" as someone eloquently put it above?

Comment: To be clear, I'm genuinely asking for more information on what's wrong with it, rather than trying to make a point.

Comment: For example: in my company, we can't modify the .NET code but we can create store procedures and triggers, so that the only thing to do is calling the web service from the sql server.

Comment: I've done SOAP POST calls from DB2 before at an enterprise level to avoid writing a stack of programs to do the same.  Watch your security, but if that's not what the SQL engine is for - why can it do it [now]?

Comment: Access data sources is exactly what SQL Server is meant to do. That's why OLEDB was invented - to make data accessible. If you source data is XML, you can use a linked server and the [Microsoft OLE DB Simple Provider](https://archive.ph/sO27G#selection-7369.0-7369.41).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got answer by powershell. What I did is open powershell in sql server then I did execute following code in powershell.

```
$http_Request= New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
$Result = $http_Request.downloadString("url")
```

Comment: How to execute those script in a sp_procedure?

Answer (score 22):

I got another answer as well. I created procedure like follows

```
CREATE procedure HTTP_Request( @sUrl varchar(200))
As


Declare
@obj int
,@hr int
,@msg varchar(255)


 exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
if @hr <> 0 begin Raiserror('sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0
failed', 16,1) return end


exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl, false
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' goto eh end


exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type',
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' goto
eh end


exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, ''
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end

 exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
return
eh:
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
Raiserror(@msg, 16, 1)
return
GO
```

I called the stored procedure with url

```
USE [master]
GO

 DECLARE    @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[HTTP_Request]
    @sUrl = N'url'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Thank you guys to make me work this.

Comment: I got message `SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.sp_OACreate' of component 'Ole Automation Procedures' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.`

Comment: This link should help you get past the blocked access to procedure error.
http://sqlsolace.blogspot.com/2009/09/sql-server-blocked-access-to-procedure.html

Answer (score 6):

That really helped me @niren.

Thought I'd post my amendment that puts it in scalar function and allows you to get the service response. Only downside is scalar funcs can't raiserrors so there's something to think about catching elsewhere.

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_HttpPOST]
(
    @sUrl varchar(8000)      
)
returns varchar(8000)
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @obj int 
    DECLARE @hr  int 
    DECLARE @msg varchar(8000)    


    exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
    if @hr <> 0 begin set @Msg = 'sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed' return @Msg end

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl, false
    if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' goto eh end

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' goto eh end

    exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, ''
    if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end

     EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @Obj,'ResponseText',@msg OUTPUT
    IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Obj

    exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj

    RETURN @msg

    eh:
    exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
    return @msg
END
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: screenshot]

The most flexible approach here is to use a CLR User Defined Function, which you could simply define in C# as follows;

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlString http(SqlString url)
{
    var wc = new WebClient();
    var html = wc.DownloadString(url.Value);
    return new SqlString (html);
}
```

Full installation instructions are here - https://github.com/infiniteloopltd/SQLHttp

Comment: This is very convenient.  The instruction includes the assembly bits so you don't have to do compille the code.

Answer (score 5):

Made this monster for my own needs

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RequestHttpWebService]
    @Url varchar(1024),
    @HttpMethod varchar(10),
    @ParamsValues varchar(1024),    -- param1=value&param2=value
    @SoapAction varchar(1024) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    if @HttpMethod in ('get','GET') and len(@ParamsValues) > 0
    begin
        set @Url = @Url + '?' + @ParamsValues
    end

    declare @obj int
        ,@response varchar(8000)
        ,@responseXml xml
        ,@status varchar(50)
        ,@statusText varchar(1024)
        ,@method varchar(10) = (case when @HttpMethod in ('soap','SOAP') then 'POST' else @HttpMethod end)

    exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj out
    exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', null, @method, @Url, false

    if @HttpMethod in ('get','GET')
    begin
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
    end
    else if @HttpMethod in ('post','POST')
    begin
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', null, @ParamsValues
    end
    else if @HttpMethod in ('soap','SOAP')
    begin
        if @SoapAction is null
            raiserror('@SoapAction is null', 10, 1)

        declare @host varchar(1024) = @Url
        if @host like 'http://%'
            set @host = right(@host, len(@host) - 7)
        else if @host like 'https://%'
            set @host = right(@host, len(@host) - 8)

        if charindex(':', @host) > 0 and charindex(':', @host) < charindex('/', @host)
            set @host = left(@host, charindex(':', @host) - 1)
        else 
            set @host = left(@host, charindex('/', @host) - 1)

        declare @envelope varchar(8000) = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><{action} xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{params}</{action}></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>'
        declare @params varchar(8000) = '' 

        WHILE LEN(@ParamsValues) > 0
        BEGIN
            declare @param varchar(256),
                    @value varchar(256)

            IF charindex('&', @ParamsValues) > 0
            BEGIN

                SET @param = left(@ParamsValues, charindex('&', @ParamsValues) - 1)
                set @value = RIGHT(@param, len(@param) - charindex('=', @param))
                set @param = left(@param, charindex('=', @param) - 1)
                set @params = @params + '<' + @param + '>' + @value + '</'+ @param + '>'
                SET @ParamsValues = right(@ParamsValues, LEN(@ParamsValues) - LEN(@param + '=' + @value + '&'))
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                set @value = RIGHT(@ParamsValues, len(@ParamsValues) - charindex('=', @ParamsValues))
                set @param = left(@ParamsValues, charindex('=', @ParamsValues) - 1)

                set @params = @params + '<' + @param + '>' + @value + '</'+ @param + '>'
                SET @ParamsValues = NULL
            END
        END

        set @envelope = replace(@envelope, '{action}', @SoapAction)
        set @envelope = replace(@envelope, '{params}', @params)

        set @SoapAction = 'http://tempuri.org/' + @SoapAction

        print @host
        print @SoapAction
        print @envelope

        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Host', @host
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'SOAPAction', @SoapAction
        exec sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send', null, @envelope
    end

    exec sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response out
    exec sp_OADestroy @obj

    select @status as [status], @statusText as [statusText], @response as [response]

END

GO
```

Comment: It does the http but it always return 0

Comment: Seems to work but you're not putting anything into `@status` and `@statusText`

Answer (score 2):

the correct way is to buil a CLR, which will contain a C# code to send http/s request,
since we want to avoid memory leaks and security issues, which using old way like sp_OACreate can cause.

for example :

```
     var request = 
   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com. /recepticle.aspx");
    var postData = "thing1=hello";
    postData += "&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;thing2=world";
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Method = "POST";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   request.ContentLength = data.Length;
   using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
     }
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   var responseString = new     StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();`
```

using sp_OACreate is less secure, while CLR can be signed and check by you.

Answer (score 1):

With these codes you can read Html Code from web pages through Httprequest or run SOAP web services.

Make HTTP request from SQLserver.

Send HTTP request via SQL Server.

Calling a SOAP webservice from SQL Server TSQL stored procedure.

Save Http Response To File.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[stp_HttpRequest]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--1400/02/16-18:06
--Mahmood Khezrian
--Sp For Get Data (Page Html Or Webservice Result) From Web.
--Can Run Any Method (Get - Post , ....)
--Can Run Soap WebService
CREATE   proc [dbo].[stp_HttpRequest] 
     @URI           varchar(max) = N''     
    ,@MethodName    [sysname] = N'Post'
    ,@RequestBody   nvarchar(max) = N''             --Neded For Run Soap Webservices , Soap XML Data Parameters
    ,@SoapAction    varchar(500)                    --Neded For Run Soap Webservices
    ,@UserName      [sysname]                       --(Optonal) Domain\UserName or UserName 
    ,@Password      [sysname]                       --(Optonal)
    ,@ResponseText  nvarchar(max) output            --Return Responce Data With This Variable
    ,@ExportToFile  nvarchar(max)=Null              --If Pass This Parameter , After Run Request Save Responce Data (Returned Value) To File.
/*With ENCRYPTION*/ As
    Set NoCount ON;
    Declare @ErrorCode  int
    Set @ErrorCode = -1
    /*Begin Transaction stp_HttpRequest*/
    Begin Try
        if (@MethodName = '')
            RaisError (N'Method Name must be set.',16,1);

        if (Patindex(N'%{RandomFileName}%',@ExportToFile)>0) Begin
            Declare @FileName [sysname]
            Set @FileName = Format(GetDate(),N'yyyyMMddHHmmss')+N'_'+Replace(NewID(),'-','')
            Set @ExportToFile = Replace(@ExportToFile,N'{RandomFileName}',@FileName)
        End--if
        Set @RequestBody = REPLACE(@RequestBody,'&','&amp;')
        Set @ResponseText = N'FAILED'

        Declare @objXmlHttp int
        Declare @hResult int
        Declare @source varchar(255), @desc varchar(255) 

        Set @ErrorCode = -100
        Exec @hResult = sp_OACreate N'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @objXmlHttp OUT
        IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                        source = @source, 
                        description = @desc, 
                        FailPoint = N'Create failed MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', 
                        MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'Create failed MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.',16,1);
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = -2
        -- open the destination URI with Specified method 
        Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'open', Null, @MethodName, @URI, N'false', @UserName, @Password
        if (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'Open failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'Open failed.',16,1);
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = -300
        -- Set Timeout 
        --Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'setTimeouts', Null, 5000,5000,15000,30000
        Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'setTimeouts', Null, 10000,10000,30000,60000
        if (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'SetTimeouts failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'SetTimeouts failed.',16,1);
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = -400
        -- set request headers 
        Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'setRequestHeader', Null, N'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
        if (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'SetRequestHeader failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'SetRequestHeader (Content-Type) failed.',16,1);
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = -500
        -- set soap action 
        if (IsNull(@SoapAction,'')!='') Begin
            Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'setRequestHeader', Null, N'SOAPAction', @SoapAction 
            IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
                Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
                Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                    source = @source, 
                    description = @desc, 
                    FailPoint = N'SetRequestHeader (SOAPAction) failed', 
                    MedthodName = @MethodName 
                RaisError (N'SetRequestHeader failed.',16,1);
            End--if
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = -600
        --Content-Length
        Declare @len int
        set @len = len(@RequestBody) 
        Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'setRequestHeader', Null, N'Content-Length', @len 
        IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'SetRequestHeader (Content-Length) failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'SetRequestHeader failed.',16,1);
        End--if

        -- if you have headers in a Table called RequestHeader you can go through them with this 
        /* 
        Set @ErrorCode = -700
        Declare @HeaderKey varchar(500), @HeaderValue varchar(500) 
        Declare RequestHeader CURSOR
        LOCAL FAST_FORWARD 
        FOR
              Select      HeaderKey, HeaderValue 
              FROM RequestHeaders 
              WHERE       Method = @MethodName 
        OPEN RequestHeader 
        FETCH NEXT FROM RequestHeader 
        INTO @HeaderKey, @HeaderValue 
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            Set @ErrorCode = -800
              --Select @HeaderKey, @HeaderValue, @MethodName 
              Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, 'setRequestHeader', Null, @HeaderKey, @HeaderValue 
              IF @hResult <> 0 
              BEGIN
                    Set @ErrorCode = -900
                    Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
                    Select      hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                          source = @source, 
                          description = @desc, 
                          FailPoint = 'SetRequestHeader failed', 
                          MedthodName = @MethodName 
                    RaisError (N'SetRequestHeader failed.',16,1);
              END
              FETCH NEXT FROM RequestHeader 
              INTO @HeaderKey, @HeaderValue 
        END
        CLOSE RequestHeader 
        DEALLOCATE RequestHeader 
        */ 

        Set @ErrorCode = -1000
        -- send the request 
        Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objXmlHttp, N'send', Null, @RequestBody 
        IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'Send failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'Send failed.',16,1);
        End--if
        Declare @StatusText varchar(1000), @Status varchar(1000) 
        
        Set @ErrorCode = -1100
        -- Get status text 
        Exec sp_OAGetProperty @objXmlHttp, N'StatusText', @StatusText out
        Exec sp_OAGetProperty @objXmlHttp, N'Status', @Status out
        Select @Status As Status, @StatusText As statusText, @MethodName As MethodName
        -- Get response text 
        Declare @Json Table (Result ntext)
        Declare @Xml xml

        Set @ErrorCode = -1200
        Insert  @Json(Result)
        Exec @hResult = dbo.sp_OAGetProperty @objXmlHttp, N'ResponseText'

        Set @ErrorCode = -1300
        --Exec @hResult = dbo.sp_OAGetProperty @objXmlHttp, N'ResponseText', @ResponseText out
        IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
            Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
            Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                source = @source, 
                description = @desc, 
                FailPoint = N'ResponseText failed', 
                MedthodName = @MethodName 
            RaisError (N'ResponseText failed.',16,1);
        END--if
        
        Set @ErrorCode = -1400
        --Set @ResponseText=Replicate(Convert(varchar(max),N'1'),1000000)
        if (IsNull(@SoapAction,'')!='') Begin
            Select @Xml=CAST(Replace(Replace(Replace(Cast(Result As nvarchar(max)),N'utf-8',N'utf-16'),N'.0,',N','),N'.00,',N',') As XML)
            From @Json
            
            Set @ErrorCode = -1500
            Select @ResponseText = x.Rec.query(N'./*').value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
            From @Xml.nodes(N'.') as x(Rec)
            
        End--if 
        Else Begin
            Select @ResponseText= Result From @Json
        End--Else

        Set @ErrorCode = -1600
        --Export To File
        if (IsNull(@ExportToFile,'')!='') Begin
            Declare @objToFile int
            Declare @FileID     int

            Set @ErrorCode = -1700
            --Create Object
            Exec @hResult = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @objToFile OUT 
            IF (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
                Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
                Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                            source = @source, 
                            description = @desc, 
                            FailPoint = N'Create failed Scripting.FileSystemObject', 
                            MedthodName = @MethodName 
                RaisError (N'Create failed Scripting.FileSystemObject.',16,1);
            End--if

            Set @ErrorCode = -1800
            --Create Or Open File
            Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod @objToFile, 'OpenTextFile'  , @FileID OUT, @ExportToFile,2,1,-1
            if (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
                Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
                Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                    source = @source, 
                    description = @desc, 
                    FailPoint = N'OpenTextFile failed', 
                    MedthodName = @MethodName 
                RaisError (N'OpenTextFile failed.',16,1);
            End--if

            Set @ErrorCode = -1900
            --Write Data To File
            Exec @hResult = sp_OAMethod  @FileID, 'Write', Null, @ResponseText
            if (@hResult <> 0 ) Begin
                Exec sp_OAGetErrorInfo @objXmlHttp, @source OUT, @desc OUT
                Select hResult = convert(varbinary(4), @hResult), 
                    source = @source, 
                    description = @desc, 
                    FailPoint = N'Write To File failed', 
                    MedthodName = @MethodName 
                RaisError (N'Write To File failed.',16,1);
            End--if

            Set @ErrorCode = -2000
            --Close File
            Exec sp_OAMethod  @FileID, 'Close'
            --Delete Objects
            Exec sp_OADestroy @FileID 
            Exec sp_OADestroy @objToFile 
            
        End--if

        Set @ErrorCode = 0
        /*If (@@TranCount > 0)
            Commit Transaction stp_HttpRequest*/
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        /*If (@@TranCount > 0)
            Rollback Transaction stp_HttpRequest*/
        Exec [dbo].[stp_GetErrorInfo]
    End Catch
    Exec sp_OADestroy @objXmlHttp
    Return @ErrorCode
GO
--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//
--Example For Run Soap WebService
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @URI varchar(max)
DECLARE @MethodName sysname
DECLARE @RequestBody nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SoapAction varchar(500)
DECLARE @UserName sysname=''
DECLARE @Password sysname=''
DECLARE @ResponseText nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @intA   nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @intB   nvarchar(10)

Set @intA = N'100'
Set @intB = N'200'


Set @URI = N'http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx'
Set @MethodName = N'POST'
Set @RequestBody = 
N'<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><intA>'+@intA+'</intA><intB>'+@intB+'</intB></Add>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>'
Set @SoapAction = N'http://tempuri.org/Add'


EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[stp_HttpRequest] 
   @URI
  ,@MethodName
  ,@RequestBody
  ,@SoapAction
  ,@UserName
  ,@Password
  ,@ResponseText OUTPUT

Print @ResponseText
Print Len(@ResponseText)
Go
--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//--//
--Example For Feach Data From Website
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @URI varchar(max)
DECLARE @MethodName sysname
DECLARE @RequestBody nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @SoapAction varchar(500)
DECLARE @UserName sysname
DECLARE @Password sysname
DECLARE @ResponseText nvarchar(max)
Declare @ExportToFile   nvarchar(max)



Set @URI = N'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407338/how-can-i-make-http-request-from-sql-server'
Set @MethodName = N'GET'
Set @RequestBody = N''
Set @SoapAction = N''
Set @ExportToFile = N'C:\Temp\Export\{RandomFileName}.html'

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[stp_HttpRequest] 
   @URI
  ,@MethodName
  ,@RequestBody
  ,@SoapAction
  ,@UserName
  ,@Password
  ,@ResponseText OUTPUT
  ,@ExportToFile

Print @ResponseText
Print Len(@ResponseText)
Go
```