# Can't use sp_configure in remote Sql server

Tags: sql-server, remote-server

I used sq_configure to use OLE automation process to send http request from SQL server like

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

and then I built one stored procedure called HTTP_Request as shown below

```
CREATE procedure HTTP_Request( @sUrl varchar(200))
As

Declare
@obj int
,@hr int
,@msg varchar(255)

exec @hr = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
if @hr <> 0 begin Raiserror('sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0
failed', 16,1) return end

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @sUrl, false
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Open failed' goto eh end

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type',
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod setRequestHeader failed' goto
eh end

exec @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj, send, NULL, ''
if @hr <>0 begin set @msg = 'sp_OAMethod Send failed' goto eh end

exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
return
eh:
exec @hr = sp_OADestroy @obj
Raiserror(@msg, 16, 1)
return
GO
```

and I called the stored procedure as

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE    @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[HTTP_Request]
@sUrl = N'url'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

It was working fine in my local sql server, I can able to send the http request from database.

Now My problem is I got access to remote sql server where I suppose to use the same thing as I did in my local system, but when I try to execute sp_configure I can't. I got error as

> could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'

any idea?
Is this problem with access restriction?

Comment: Is this "remote SQL Server" running on SQL Azure / Windows Azure SQL Database?

Comment: this is my remote database version:Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 11.0.9099.37 
 Jul  5 2013 23:16:50 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 3):

You can't run `sp_configure` on WASD, sorry. And even if you could, you would not be able to invoke OA methods. You will need to find another way to hit your web page (e.g. hit it from your application instead of from a stored procedure - arguably where it should happen anyway).

Comment: what application should I create to achieve my requirement? see my [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407338/how-can-i-make-http-request-from-sql-server)

Comment: @niren well, you could use PowerShell, like your answer there, or C#, or - I don't know - whatever you're good at. But if you're using WASD you won't be able to host it *on* the SQL Server. Maybe you should be using a Windows Azure VM instead, where you can run proper (non-WASD) SQL Server and whatever other applications or scripts you need.

Comment: Typically I don't have access to choose which remote database to use, My company already have been using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM). Now they have created a login for me to use, so I need to run my application in this given database. Is there any other way to my application work?. As you know I can't use Power Shell as well in remote sql server.

Comment: I don't know because I don't fully understand your requirements. It sounds like you are trying to keep two databases in sync but quite frankly I think you're going to need a consultant to help you (and no I'm not offering to be that consultant).