# Executing webjobs via SQL server Stored Procedure

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have a very simple **C# console exe**. My code deletes a blob from a particular blob storage. It takes a couple of command-line arguments - container name & blob name and deletes the blob whenever triggered.
Now, I want to schedule this exe as a webjob.

I have a couple of questions -

1. How can **I manually trigger this webjob since it takes command line arguments**?
2. Is there any way that I can **trigger this webjob via a SQL server stored procedure**?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Comment: @JasonPan no, did not help!

Comment: What do you think is the problem in my answer? What actions have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the stored procedure to send http requests to fulfill your needs.**

## Steps

1. You can use [the Kudu Webjob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job) to invoke your function.
2. Create HttpRequest Method in sql server.

   *Related post*

   [How can I make HTTP request from SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407338/how-can-i-make-http-request-from-sql-server)