# How to request a bearer token directly from SQL Server using a certificate

Tags: sql-server, rest, authentication, sql-server-2016, bearer-token

I am tasked with writing a SQL Server stored procedure to request a bearer token from a vendor site using their API.

The vendor site issued me two files of type `.cer` and `.key`. When I import these files into Postman, I can request a bearer token and receive the appropriate response after including two additional values, the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

I am looking for documentation on how to do the same from SQL Server.  There are almost NO posts anywhere about using a security certificate from a SQL Server stored procedure directly. The writer already has a bearer token to use in their code in all the posts I found, and assumes you do, too. This makes me wonder if this can be done from a SQL Server stored procedure?

I combined the two files into a `.pfx` file and imported into the Windows Server certificate store where the SQL Server instance resides. It is currently in the Personal store (it can be moved to another store, if need be).

Am I going about this wrong? I could always use Postman to get the bearer token, then consume into SQL Server using the xp_cmdshell. It just seems like this should be easier than that.

I can successfully get a bearer token using Postman. I cannot find instructions anywhere for how to do the same thing within SQL Server.

SQL Server 2016 running on Windows Server 2016. The vendor is the payroll company ADP.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't offer bearer token authentication (nor should it), partly because it doesn't offer a rest API (nor should it). Only an app in front of SQL Server would do that.

Comment: SQL server is a database engine for storing relational data, it's not an application builder. Therefore it's the last place you should be calling a REST endpoint from.

Comment: Could you consider using PowerShell, instead? You can invoke PowerShell as SQL Agent job steps directly from SQL Agent jobs. You could use this to periodically collect the data you need and store it in the database.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting, you can call rest apis directly with SQL Server, but only from Azure SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-invoke-external-rest-endpoint-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&tabs=request-headers

Comment: "I am tasked with writing a SQL Server stored procedure to request a bearer token from a vendor site using their API." SQL and API are just not things that should be mixing.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much **not recommended**. You should have an app or script with application code in between SQL Server and the other environment, rather than trying do this in SQL directly.

Nevertheless, it *should* be possible. What you need is to send the appropriate HTTP requests to get the token, and that can be accomplished using the information here:

> [How can I make HTTP request from SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407338/how-can-i-make-http-request-from-sql-server)

The link is talking about connecting to Tomcat, rather than a REST API, but the basic principle of using HTTP is the same.

And again: *not recommended*.

Comment: I should have mentioned why I am attempting this from SQL Server.  My application is in C#.  I know I can make API calls using C#, but then calls would be made by dozens of different machines throughout my organization.  Both myself and the vendor I am working with would prefer this process be centralized and, therefore, only coming from a single machine.  That being said, if there is a way to do this external to SQL server that would still be centralized, and allow data to pass to and from SQL server, I am open to suggestions?